# Heroku Rails Gem cannot find an executable in PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, heroku, path-variables

I'm deploying a Rails app on Heroku which requires a gem that looks for an executable in PATH. I put my executable inside /vendor/bin and then proceeded as below:

As explained in Heroku docs here, I created a **.profile.d** directory in the root of my app and then in it, I created a file called **path.sh**. In path.sh, I set the PATH variable like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/app/vendor/bin"
```

or this

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/vendor/bin
```

But neither seems to work. The app is deployed successfully but when I run it, I see an application error, and in my logs, I see that this executable could not be found in PATH, thus the application crashed. The script (*.profile.d/path.sh*) is run for sure though, because in my Heroku logs, I am able to see other commands and the print outs I put in the very same file.

Does anyone know what to do in order to make this work? Thanks in advance.